# Using php inside javascript

Tags: php, theme-development, html, date

I have got the following code in a javascript(jquery) file  called custom.js:

```
     var gapinvite = new Date();


    gapinvite = new Date(2014, 06 - 1, 2);
    $('.days').countdown({
        until: gapinvite,
        layout: '{dn} {dl}',

        /* Set your timezone */
        timezone: +7
    });
```

1.Now i want  a user to be able to change the above date. I have created a theme options page called theme-options.php

2.I am  using `<?php require_once('theme-options.php'); ?>` in the functions.php to link to theme-options.php.

3.This is theme-options.php:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'director_create_menu');
function director_create_menu() {
add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', ' Theme Options',
'Theme Options', 'administrator', __FILE__,
'director_settings_page');
add_action( 'admin_init', 'director_register_settings' );
}
function director_register_settings() {
register_setting( 'director-settings-group', 'director_date' );
}

div class="wrap">
  <h2>Theme Settings</h2>
  <form id="landingOptions" method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'director-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
<tr valign="top">
          <th scope="row">Date:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="2014, 06 - 1, 2" name="director_date"
            value="<?php print get_option('director_date');
            ?>" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      <tr valign="top">
      <th scope="row">Time Zone:</th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="+5" name="director_timezone"
        value="<?php print get_option('director_timezone');
        ?>" />
      </td>
    </tr>
     <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>"   />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Basically what is happening is that there is a theme options page.A user gives a date inside it. Now i want to use that date inside the javascript file.
If I had to use it inside index.php it would've been

```
<?php $date = get_option('director_date'); ?>
<?php if( $date ) : ?> <?php echo $date; ?><?php endif; ?>);
```

and

```
<?php $timezone = get_option('director_timezone'); ?>
<?php if( $timezone ) : ?> <?php echo $timezone; ?><?php endif; ?>);
```

. However this is javascript. How do i implement such an action here?

Comment: A simple solution is to echo the date in a hidden input field with an ID. Then you can use getElementByID() or a jquery selector $("#id").val() to get that value.

Comment: Could you please give it in detail in an answer.I feel that you are moving in the right direction

Comment: As written, this question is off-topic for WPSE. It is a **PHP/JavaScript** question that merely happens in the *context* of WordPress, but is not *specific* to WordPress.

Comment: Well it relates to wordpress because wp_localize_script can be used and it happens in wordpress only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-instantiate your countdown timer only after the date has been changed and saved, then, something to the effect of:

```
//In your custom.js file....
//make sure your localized data is a dependency of your custom.js file so you have proper scope to local data
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var date, gapinvite;

    date = $('input[name="director_date"]');

    if ( date.val().length ) {

         gapinvite = new Date(Data.date); //if localizing variable

         /* OR */

        //gapinvite = new Date(date.val()); //if accessing variable directly from value attribute

    } else {

         /* if gapinvite should always start from 2014, 06 - 1, 2 as default do... */
         gapinvite = new Date(2014, 06 - 1, 2);

         /* if gapinvite should always start from today as default do... */
         //gapinvite = new Date(); //uncomment if required

         /* 
          * if gapinvite should always come from your default placeholder value do...
          * how you generate that value is up to you.
          */
         //gapinvite = new Date(date.attr('placeholder'));  //uncomment if required
    }

    $('.days').countdown({
        until: gapinvite,
        layout: '{dn} {dl}',

        /* Set your timezone */
        timezone: gapinvite.getTimezoneOffset()
    });

});
```

This will grab the default placeholder date if the director_date value attribute is empty, otherwise it will grab the value supplied by the user and instantiate the countdown timer accordingly.

In future, questions strictly related to JavaScript and jQuery should be asked at [Stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Edit: remove unnecessary timezone variable, calculate offset directly within object property value.

Comment: Wait let me try it out. And thanks for your answer. I would refer to [SO] next time

Comment: @user3274745 If you are more clear on what you are looking for maybe we can help. As it stands, the above will do what you want, but if you wish to achieve it by other means, you need to explain exactly what those means are and why you want to do it that way.

Comment: Wait let me try your answer.

Comment: Well @userabuser there is a slight complication.Have a look at the edited  code that i have added above now. It would help a lot.Again thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3274745 I've updated the answer but I still don't see what your problem is. What is the slight complication? The above code will work, assuming you are using it properly. If you are not, then it will not work. If you are unsure, please tell us what you are unsure about, if you see errors, what errors do you see? Etc.

Comment: Have a look i have added the timezone. The timezone inside the existing code confuses me.Have a look at the updated question

Comment: I want to get the timezone from the theme options too but the above code doesn't do that. Thank you for keeping track.

Comment: @user3274745 Last edit... that should be all you need.

Comment: No problem, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp localize script()` in order to send data to your Javascript file.

After enqueuing custom.js you can then pass data to it like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script' );
wp_localize_script('custom_script', 'Data', array('date' => get_option('director_date')));
```

You can then access the date in your javascript file like this:

```
console.log(Data.date);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It's a bit more complicated. The answer below works but with a slight problem still being discussed.